# Extracting Key:Value from column fields in Hive

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, hadoop, hive

I'm currently learning/testing Hive and can't seem to find a suitable solution to this problem: 
I have log files which look like this:

```
IP, Date, Time, URL, Useragent
```

Which I have currently in a Table with these Columns. These Columns are delimited by '\t' but **URL** has been given some specific client information looking somewhat like this:

`example.org/log.gif?userID=xxx&sex=m&age=y&subscriber=y&lastlogin=ddd`

and I want to create a new table with these given value-pairs: `userID, sex, age, subscriber, lastlogin` another problem being that the value-pairs are not always complete, or some are missing. Like this:

`example.org/log.gif?userID=xxx&sex=m&age=y&subscriber=y&lastlogin=ddd`

`example.org/log.gif?userID=xxx&sex=m&age=y&lastlogin=`

Which makes Hive's  `... format delimited fields terminated by '&';` afaik useless in this case because it would lead to wrong values in columns.

Is there a way to solve this problem in Hive with SQL and regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done, albeit with two Hive tables. You first load data into one table with the columns:

```
IP, Date, Time, URL, Useragent
```

Here I recommend using an `EXTERNAL` Hive table - you aren't parsing the data and this Hive table doesn't need to exist for very long, so simply place Hive metadata on top of it:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE raw_log (
  ip                string,
  date              string,
  time              string,
  url               string,
  useragent         string
)
LOCATION '<hdfs_location_of_the_raw_log_folder>';
```

Then use an `INSERT INTO` query with the Hive `regexp_extract(string subject, string pattern, int index)` method (see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) to load it into the "final" table with the correct columns.

You can also write your own UDF which would enable you to better-handle the incomplete/missing values that you mention, albeit with the tradeoff that you have to re-compile and re-deploy a JAR every time the input data's format changes (see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HivePlugins).

Comment: I tried it with a table(userID) and successfully inserted all userIDs from my raw_data table. But when I try insert multiple values into a new table `userdata(userID, age)` I get an error: `insert into table userdate regexp_extract(get userid), regexp_extract(get age) as userID,age from raw_data;` produces: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:125 Invalid table alias or column reference 'age': (possible column names are: "all columns from raw_data")

Comment: That method accepts three argument, but you've only given it one, and with a space in. I'm not sure where "get" is coming from. My regex is poor so I can't be of a lot of help, but look at the Hive UDF page I linked to see some usage examples.

Comment: Sorry I used a bit of pseudocode there, I'm actually giving it three arguments and the regex works (thought not 100% correct at the moment) the SQL syntax however doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: Sure: `INSERT INTO TABLE user_data SELECT regexp_extract(url, 'userID=(..........)', 0), regexp_extract(url, 'age=(..)', 0) AS userid,age FROM raw_data;`

Comment: `INSERT INTO TABLE user_data SELECT regexp_extract(url, 'userID=(..........)', 0) AS userid, regexp_extract(url, 'age=(..)', 0) AS age FROM raw_data;` will fix that.